# Emacs Org-Mode: Customize date picker layout

Tags: emacs, datepicker, customization, org-mode

I can insert a date in Org-Mode by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>. This brings up the nice date picker that allows me to choose a date from the calendar.

By default date picker starts each week on a Sunday. I'm more used to seeing a week start on a Monday.

I know it's a minor thing, but is it possible to customize the org-mode date picker to display weeks starting on a *Monday* rather than on a Sunday? I've searched but I can't seem to find any mention of whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
(setq calendar-week-start-day 1)
```

org-mode uses calendar; that's why searching for a configuration param in org-mode did not work.